# Interface and Delegate Casting

Tags: c#, .net, interface, delegates

Delegate:

```
    public delegate Result SalesforceAPIOnFailureEventHandler<T1, T2>(T1 sObject, T2 rawObject, string reason) where T1 : SalesforceApex.sObject;
```

Interface:

```
    public interface iSalesforceAPIHelperConfiguration<T1, T2> where T1 : SalesforceApex.sObject
    {
        SalesforceAPIOnFailureEventHandler<T1, T2> OnFailure { get; set; }
    }
```

Class:

```
    public class SalesforceAPIHelperConfiguration<T1, T2> : iSalesforceAPIHelperConfiguration<T1, T2> where T1 : SalesforceApex.sObject
    {
       public SalesforceAPIOnFailureEventHandler<T1, T2> OnFailure { get; set; }
    }
```

Function:

```
    Type typeArg = typeof(SalesforceAPIHelperConfiguration<,>);
    Type[] typeArgs = { SalesforceApex.Account, typeof(object) };
    Type typeClass = typeArg.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
    iSalesforceAPIHelperConfiguration<SalesforceApex.sObject, object> salesforceAPIHelperConfiguration = (iSalesforceAPIHelperConfiguration<SalesforceApex.sObject, object>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeClass);
```

So basically, I need to create a class of the type SalesforceAPIHelperConfiguration as shown above. I am able to create the class, however I am not able to cast it to my interface. How can I accomplish this?

My intention is to create classes of type SalesforceAPIHelperConfiguration and supplying the generic parameters at runtime. I would then need to initialize the event handler OnFailure which will be exposed through the interface.

Comment: What is the error/exception message?

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'SalesforceAPIHelperConfiguration`2[SalesforceApex.Account,System.Object]' to type 'SalesforceAPIHelperConfiguration`2[SalesforceApex.sObject,System.Object]'.

Comment: OK. Note that the reflection part is not relevant here, it only distracts.

Comment: I am using reflection since the typeArgs SalesforceApex.Account can vary.

Comment: But it does not matter for the question. You could/should have created a [MCVE] without it and then you would find many duplicates.

Comment: I included it because the last line where the casting is happening, is where the error occurs.

Comment: But you can create a MCVE without reflection. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

Your interface is *invariant* with respect to `T1` and `T2`, since it both outputs values using those types and accepts values as input using those types.  Because it is invariant, you can't treat an `iSalesforceAPIHelperConfiguration<someDerivedSFObject, someType>` as if it's a `iSalesforceAPIHelperConfiguration<SalesforceApex.sObject, object>`.  If the runtime let you do so, then you could pass in an object (for either type) that didn't actually match the actual generic arguments of the real concrete type.

Comment: @JEPAAB No.  What you're asking is fundamentally nonsensical.  You either need to make the interface itself logically covariant, by removing all operations that allow it to accept values using the generic arguments, or you can't sensibly treat the interface covariantly.

Comment: So in my case you mean to change the event handler OnFailure to do not include the generic parameters? If yes, how can I assure that T1 is of a specified type?

Comment: @JEPAAB Without knowing what you *actually* need to do, I cannot meaningfully suggest solutions.  What you have asked to do is impossible, and given the information in your question, that's really all that I can say.  If *all* of the requirements you've listed are really necessary, then this is impossible, if some can be removed, then you may be able to make it work, but without knowing which requirements may not be necessary, there's nothing I could suggest.

Comment: My intention is to create classes of type SalesforceAPIHelperConfiguration and supplying the generic parameters at runtime. I would then need to initialize the event handler OnFailure which will be exposed through the interface.

Comment: @JEPAAB If the interface *only* exposes a setter, then you can make the interface covariant, and the delegate contravariant and then the cast will be valid.